# Exception while binidng form to bean using Spring MVC, JSR 303 Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, datetime-format

I have a following spring form:input tag in my jsp which accepts a date.

```
<form:input type="text" id="fromDate" path="fromDate" />
```

and  I have a corresponding Java bean to bind the user entered date to fromDate property of the bean.

```
@NotNull
@Past
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private Date fromDate;
```

When the users enters the date in "MM/dd/yyyy" format I am not getting any exception and the value is getting set to the bean variable properly.

However when the user enters date in a different format ( ex : 23/12/2012) or invalid date ( ex: 060412009324092014) I am getting the following exception .

Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property fromDate; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.validation.constraints.Past @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date for value 060412009324092014; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse 060412009324092014

Please help to display a valid message instead of the exception on the page.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Look what exception says: `Unable to parse 060412009324092014` Is this you are passing as string? The string should be in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. Check the string that is passed.

Comment: Since it is on a webpage there is no way to control what user is entering. Want to validate the input and show a error message if the entered value is not correct.

Comment: OK so in this case it should show the error, validate the form using `BindingResult bindingResult` and call `bindingResult.hasErrors()` in controller methods.

Comment: Where will I validate the form? execution never goes to the controller, as the binding of input data happens before that and the exception is thrown.

Comment: Please show your controller code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by having the following property.

typeMismatch.bean.fromDate = Invalid from date!

Thanks
Mark.